# Is it possible to distinguish grayscale from (scanned) monochrome within a shell script?

Tags: scripting, imagemagick

I have several thousand images that I want to run various IM commands on depending on which of three categories they fall into:

- Color (often with bright colors)
- Grayscale (scanned from paper, the "white" often has a yellowish tinge)
- Monochrome (scanned, with the yellowish tinge, as above)

Can this be sorted out from a shell script?

*Color Example #1*

[image: Color Example #1]

*Grayscale Example #1*

[image]

*Monochrome Examples #1 and #2*

[image]        [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the Hue and Saturation would be good discriminants for the colour image especially. A mono or grayscale image is very unsaturated, so its mean saturation will tend to be low whereas it will be higher for a colour image. Also, the hue (basically colour) of a colour image will tend to vary a lot between the different colours whereas the hue will tend to be a fairly constant value for a grey or mono image, so the amount of variation in the Hue should be a good measure - i.e. its standard deviation.

We can calculate the mean saturation using ImageMagick like this:

```
convert image.png -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate -format "%[mean]" info:
```

and the standard deviation of the Hue like this:

```
convert image.png -colorspace HSL -channel H -separate -format "%[standard-deviation]" info:
```

So, if we put all that together in a bash script and run it over your images we get this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in colour.png grey.png mono.png; do
   SatMean=$(convert $i -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate -format "%[mean]" info:)
   HueStdDev=$(convert $i -colorspace HSL -channel H -separate -format "%[standard-deviation]" info:)
   echo $i: Mean saturation: $SatMean, Hue Std-Dev: $HueStdDev
done
```

**Output**

```
colour.png: Mean saturation: 17,807.9, Hue Std-Dev: 16,308.3
grey.png: Mean saturation: 7,019.67, Hue Std-Dev: 2,649.01
mono.png: Mean saturation: 14,606.1, Hue Std-Dev: 1,097.36
```

And it seems to differentiate quite well - I have added the thousands separator for clarity. The range of the values is based on your IM Quantisation level - mine is Q16 so the range is 0-65535.

Differentiating the *mono* from the *grey* is harder. Essentially, in the *mono* image you have a more starkly bi-modal histogram, and in the grey image, you have a more *continuous* histogram. We can plot the histograms like this:

```
convert colour.png histogram:colorhist.png
convert grey.png histogram:greyhist.png
convert mono.png histogram:monohist.png
```

[image: colour]

[image: grey]

[image: mono]

**Updated**

To differentiate between the *greyscale* and *mono*, I want to look at the pixels in the middle of the histogram, basically ignoring blacks (and near blacks) and whites (and near whites). So I can do this to set all blacks and near blacks and whites and near whites to fully black:

```
convert image.png                                \
  -colorspace gray                               \
  -contrast-stretch 1%                           \
  -black-threshold 20%                           \
  -white-threshold 80% -fill black -opaque white \
  out.png
```

[image]

If I now clone that image and set all the pixels in the clone to black, I can then calculate the difference between the histogram-chopped image and the black one

```
convert image.png                                     \
   -colorspace gray                                   \
   -contrast-stretch 1%                               \
   -black-threshold 20%                               \
   -white-threshold 80% -fill black -opaque white     \
   \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \)                       \
   -metric ae -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
```

Now, if I calculate the total number of pixels in the image, I can derive the percentage of pixels that are in the midtones and use this as a measure of whether the image is very grey or lacking in midtones.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in colour.png grey.png mono.png; do
   SatMean=$(convert $i -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate -format "%[mean]" info:)
   HueStdDev=$(convert $i -colorspace HSL -channel H -separate -format "%[standard-deviation]" info:)
   NumMidTones=$(convert $i -colorspace gray -contrast-stretch 1% -black-threshold 20% -white-threshold 80% -fill black -opaque white \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \) -metric ae -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:)
   NumPixels=$(convert $i -ping -format "%[fx:w*h]" info:)
   PctMidTones=$((NumMidTones*100/NumPixels))
   echo $i: Mean saturation: $SatMean, Hue Std-Dev: $HueStdDev, PercentMidTones: $PctMidTones
done
```

**Output**

```
colour.png: Mean saturation: 17807.9, Hue Std-Dev: 16308.3, PercentMidTones: 70
grey.png: Mean saturation: 7019.67, Hue Std-Dev: 2649.01, PercentMidTones: 39
mono.png: Mean saturation: 14606.1, Hue Std-Dev: 1097.36, PercentMidTones: 27
```

Comment: ***+1*** -- Good approach! (I was too much occupied with my own ideas in order to come up with the simple, quite obvious Hue/Saturation distinction.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Your question's headline is misleading.

> *"Is it possible to distinguish grayscale from (scanned) monochrome within a shell script?"*

### Straightforward `identify` tells color space and bit depth

It is misleading, because all the example images you provide are in fact in `8-bit sRGB` colorspace:

```
identify https://i.stack.imgur.com/lygAE.png \
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7vBP.png \
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOCTK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lygAE.png=>lygAE.png PNG 236x216 236x216+0+0 8-bit sRGB 127KB 0.000u 0:00.000
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7vBP.png=>H7vBP.png[1] PNG 259x192 259x192+0+0 8-bit sRGB 86.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOCTK.png=>ZOCTK.png[2] PNG 264x179 264x179+0+0 8-bit sRGB 86.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

As you can see, the `identify` command (part of the ImageMagick suite of commands) can tell you the depth and color space of an image easily.

#### `identify` with `-format` parameter tells specific image properties

You can include the `-format` parameter with *'percent escapes'* in order to get to specific properties only of the image:

- **`f`** : for image file name
- **`d`** : for directory component of image
- **`z`** : for image depth
- **`r`** : for image class and color space

So try this:

```
identify -format "%f %d :   %z %r\n"        \
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/lygAE.png \
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7vBP.png \
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOCTK.png
```

Result:

```
lygAE.png //i.stack.imgur.com :   8 DirectClass sRGB 
H7vBP.png //i.stack.imgur.com :   8 DirectClass sRGB 
ZOCTK.png //i.stack.imgur.com :   8 DirectClass sRGB
```

### Convert one image to real monochrome

Now to show you how a real "monochrome" image looks like, let's convert one of your samples accordingly:

```
convert                                    \
       -colorspace gray                    \
        https://i.stack.imgur.com/lygAE.png \
       +dither                             \
       -colors 2                           \
       -depth 1                            \
        bmp3:monochrome.bmp
```

and

```
identify -format "%f :  %z %r\n" monochrome.bmp https://i.stack.imgur.com/lygAE.png
  monochrome.bmp :  1 PseudoClass Gray
       lygAE.png :  8 DirectClass sRGB
```

Here are the respective images:

[image]  [image]

### Telling the number of unique colors

If you have (as you do) all your images in sRGB color space with 8-bit depth, then in theory, each image can have as many as 16.777.216 (16 million) colors (also called "TrueColor"). However, most actual images do not use the full scope of this spectrum, and the "gray-ish" appearing images will actually use an even smaller number of them.

So ImageMagick has two other 'percent escape' to return information about images:

- **`%k`** :  returns the number of unique colors within an image. This is a *calculated* value. IM has to process the image and analyse every single pixel of it to arrive at this number.

So here is a command:

```
identify -format "%f -  number of unique colors: %k\n" \
          https://i.stack.imgur.com/lygAE.png           \
          https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7vBP.png           \
          https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOCTK.png
```

Results:

```
lygAE.png -  number of unique colors: 47583
H7vBP.png -  number of unique colors:  7987
ZOCTK.png -  number of unique colors:  5208
```

As you can see, your image with obvious coloring uses about 6 times as many uniq colors than the "gray-ish" scans do.

However, this is not necessarily so. See for instance this image:

[image: 8 different colors]

It is color, isn't it?

I generated it with this command:

```
convert -size 100x100 \
         xc:red       \
         xc:green     \
         xc:blue      \
         xc:white     \
         xc:black     \
         xc:cyan      \
         xc:magenta   \
         xc:yellow    \
        +append       \
         out.png
```

You can even count the number of unique colors by simply looking at it: 8.

Now what does `identify` tell us about it?

```
identify \
  -format "%f:\n \
            -- number of unique colors: %k\n \
            -- depth: %z\n \
            -- class/space: %r\n \
            -- image type: %[type]\n" \
   out.png
```

Result:

```
out.png:
             -- number of unique colors: 8
             -- depth: 8
             -- class/space: PseudoClass sRGB 
             -- image type: Palette
```

So a low number of unique colors does not necessarily proof that the image is "gray-ish"!

You'lll have to play with this parameters a bit and see if you can come up with a combination that helps you to correctly classify your real-world "thousands of images".

### Consider image statistics too

More values you could look at with the help of `identify -format %... filename.suffix`:

- **`%[gamma]`** :  value of image gamma
- **`%[entropy]`** :  CALCULATED: entropy of image
- **`%[kurtosis]`** :  CALCULATED: kurtosis value statistic of image
- **`%[max]`** :  CALCULATED: maximum value statistic of image
- **`%[mean]`** :  CALCULATED: mean value statistic of image
- **`%[min]`** :  CALCULATED: minimum value statistic of image
- **`%[profile:icc]`** :  ICC profile info
- **`%[profile:icm]`** :  ICM profile info

### Last hint: look at the metadata!

Just in case your images were scanned by a device that leaves its own identifying meta data behind: check for them!

The command line tool `exiftool` is a good utility to do so.

Comment: My apologies. Those weren't the full images, which are quite large (and subject to copyright issues... I thought small clips would be fair use). I did screen capture to pull relevant (or so I thought) clips.

Comment: @JohnO: So your screen capturing did introduce the sRGB 8-bit colorspace... You should provide ***real*** samples to get ***real*** answers!